# How to make use of one pipeline timestamp after it runs into another pipeline in azure data factoryy

Tags: azure

How to make use of one pipeline timestamp after it runs into another pipeline in azure data factory

Comment: Hi @Rahman, could you please edit your question to add additional information like your sample input and expected outcome or picture of your pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Parameters (for example TimeParam) in another pipeline. [image]

So that when you call this pipeline, ADF will ask you to provide the value of this parameter. You can provide anything you like.
[image]